# External Storge permission on Android 9.0-pie

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-9.0-pie

First of all I want to clarify that the device I'm working on is my car's tablet which runs Android 9 and does not have any google services(any google application is not going to work)

The tablet has a UI which sucks because I can not access any thing normally even the android settings.

How ever the developer options are opened by default and by pressing the Bluetooth version for like 10 times WIFI adb starts.

And after buying an app to control the car's tablet by adb every thing now is accessible by commands (installing apps "apk files" done by adb also)

I was having a problem granting external storage permission to any file explorer app on android 9 since all new apps tries granting the permission by directing me to the new stock android file manager and asks me to press on "use this folder" button, the problem is that the stock file manager does not exist on android 9 and the file explorer apps get to crash whenever I try to access the external storage

The solution is to have an app that asks the external storage permission as old days by the pop-up window.

(I installed MX-Player and when I tried to access the external storage it did ask the external storage permission by the pop-up window and I was able to access the video files on the flash drive.)
(How ever I want to access all files.)

And here it gets very difficult to find such an app

[Stock Android File Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5oSD.jpg)

[Stock Android File Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idphf.jpg)

[MX-Player's old permission pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUF3E.jpg)

I tried installing old versions of known file explorers as File Explorer +, RS File Manger etc.
but still negative :(

so before trying on the car I made a try on my phone to grant the access by this commands on my phone which runs Android 13

```
adb shell pm grant com.alphainventor.filemanager android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

```
adb shell pm grant com.alphainventor.filemanager android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

but since my phone is on Android 13 it didn't work because I should to grant the permission by the stock file manager

How ever it did work to grant the access to the camera for another application that didn't have the camera permission :)

I didn't try the last step on my car and I told my self; let me ask about this problem before trying.

I wish any body can help me to find a file explorer that accesses the external storage without directing me to the stock file manager or give away to grant the permission by an adb command :)

Comment: `granting external storage permission to any file explorer app` What are you up to,? Every app should request such permissions them selves and let the user confirm.

Comment: Usually the files app that is used to gibe access permissions to a file manager app is a system app that exists on all Android installations. May be you have accidentally disabled it? BTW: First you write your phone runs Android 9, later then you say it has Android 13 - that is a contradiction. If you have multiple device it would be good to list them at the beginning and describe what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for confusion

The device I'm working on is the car's tablet which has an Android 9-pie which I had the problem on (as I clarified above the new apps are asking for permissions by directing me to the stock fie manager, which doesn't exist on Android 9. This causes the app to crash immediately when I try to enter the flash drive. )

how ever I didn't want to use the adb command on the car so I don't miss up.
That's why I tried granting the permission on my phone which runs Android 13 first using the adb command

I wish it's clear now

Comment: I also want to clarify that installing apps on the car's tablet done by adb and the is no other way to installs apps due to not having google play store
I know that I can install other apk stores bu this threats the security of may car's system

Comment: If the car's tablet misses the system file app then that's it. This is not a regular file manager app but the system file app. You can not install system apps via adb. So complain at the tablet manufacturer about the defect system or try, if you can set the permissions via adb. BTW is there are comments from two people on your question you need the `@userxyz` link otherwise the users you answer on don't get a notification and thus may miss your answer.

Comment: @Robert
Thanks for your advice about the link feature

Comment: You can open Settings -> Apps -> (Your File Manager) -> Permissions, and grant permissions.

Comment: @VishnuSDharan Unfortunately there is no such an option :(